# if else in sql update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to implement the logic in SQL query

```
update table 
    if (column1 = null) then set column1='123'
     else set column2 = '123'
```

Answer (score 7):

Use conditional logic, something like:

```
update t
    set column1 = coalesce(column1, '123'),
        column2 = (case when column1 is null then column2 else '123' end);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE MyTable SET column1 = CASE 
                              WHEN column1 IS Null THEN '123'
                              ELSE column1
                             END,
                   column2 = CASE 
                              WHEN column1 IS Null THEN column2
                              ELSE '123'
                             END;
```